# how to prevent pointer-events:none affect a button insdide of element with this style

Tags: javascript

I want the button inside the `.container` to be clickable, even though it has the `pointer-events:none` property.

The context is this: in my real code, I must prevent that a parent div (something to the style of the div that has the class `.container`) cannot be dragged, or click pressed and dragged somewhere.

I think if there is a way to solve this, my problem is solved.
this is my code:

```js
function myFunction(){
 alert("click")
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:30vh;
  height:30vw;
  background:red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pointer-events: all` or `pointer-events: auto` to the style of your button.

```js
function myFunction(){
 alert("click")
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:30vh;
  height:30vw;
  background:red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.container button{
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
</div>
```